# How to create a multi-client socket in Python?

Tags: python, sockets, connection, client

How I can to create a multi-client socket in Python ?

Example, I have a list of X Ip Servers and I want to create a X Client Sockets:

```
IP_SERVERS = ['127.0.0.1', '127.0.0.2', '127.0.0.3']
```

How can I do that without multi-threads ?

Note:

I want to try to connect to all this IP_SERVERS without to wait the first client socket
connect to the first server.

Thank you !

Comment: Doing things in parallel is what threads are for.  Why don't you want to use them?

Answer (score 0):

```
import socket
servers = [] #add servers here
class Clients:
    def __init__(self):
       self.socket = new socket() #change this to full socket init
    def connect(self, url):
       self.socket.connect(url)
    def send(self, data):
       self.socket.send(data)
    def close(self):
       self.socket.close()

for url in servers:
    client = new Clients()
    client.connect(url)
    client.send('abcd')
    client.close()
```

Something like that ? Also this is general code just as an idea or example, it will not work if try to run it.

Threads will work better, since it will not go sequentially and wait for sockets to connect and send data etc...

Comment: It's not good because you wait for accept from the server and until you don't receive this accept, you can't create another client sockets .
Threads don't good for my idea, because sometimes you have 1000 servers ip to scan, and to create 1000 threads, that not effective, because of that i want to search other solution for my problem.

Comment: This will wait for each connection and open them one at a time. He wants to open them concurrently. Normally that would be accomplished with threads.

Comment: So if you don't want to use threads and you want concurrency how are you going to to that?

Comment: But in threads i have problem, to open 1000 threads it's not good, right ?
And i think on other solution that open socket after socket and don't wait for accept from the server to step forward to the other socket .

Comment: Why do you need to check 1000 servers ? You have to use threads, use batch of 100 and move as previous threads finishes?

Comment: Read up on thread pooling for ideas. You can always limit the number of threads you start to an efficient number. 10 threads dividing up 1000 jobs will do much better than one thread.

Comment: I need to check 1000 servers and more, because i check in a big network between all the computers that in this big network, in which computer my software found.
How much threads in need to open in the same time for make the script effective ?